# highlighting textbox content upon click

Tags: excel, vba

i've got dynamically generated userform consisting of labels, checkboxes and text boxes. is it possible to have a contents of a textbox selected when clicked? 
this is method i'm using to create textbox:

```
Set NewTextBox = MainFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
With NewTextBox
    .Name = "QtyTB" & row
    .Value = Cells(cellrow - 1 + row, 11)
    .Height = 18
    .Left = 210
    .Top = 18
    .Width = 36
    .Enabled = True
    .BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End With
```

if i was to create textbox manually i could write on_click sub for specific text box. but as i said, code generates everything from scratch.
so if there is a property, or some other way to get it done, i would be gratefull.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done by creating a class module with event handling

The following code will need a bit of adaption as there isn't much code to go on in the question...

> In a class module called TextBoxEventHandler

```
Private WithEvents FormTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal oTextBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set FormTextBox = oTextBox
End Property

Private Sub FormTextBox_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Button = 1 Then
        With FormTextBox
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

> Then in the UserForm code

```
Private CollectionOfEventHandlers As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NewTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

    For i = 0 To 4
        Set NewTextBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        With NewTextBox
            .Name = "QtyTB" & i ' Row
            .Value = "Text " & i ' Cells(cellrow - 1 + Row, 11)
            .Height = 18
            .Left = 21
            .Top = 18 + i * 25
            .Width = 36
            .Enabled = True
            .BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End With
    Next i
    Call InitialiseHandlers
End Sub

Private Function InitialiseHandlers()
    Set CollectionOfEventHandlers = New Collection
    Dim FormControl As Control
    For Each FormControl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(FormControl) = "TextBox" Then
            Dim EventHandler As TextboxEventHandler
            Set EventHandler = New TextboxEventHandler
            Set EventHandler.TextBox = FormControl
            CollectionOfEventHandlers.Add EventHandler
        End If
    Next FormControl
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked marvelously and with only very minimal code adaptation. Is there a chance You could explain Your code a bit to me on pm please? It works, but i don't know how :)