# Detect a selection change in Excel VBA ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I need to detect when a selection change is made in a listbox so I can write the value to a sheet, the moment an item is selected or deselected.

There doesn't seem to be an event to capture this.  OnChange doesnt get triggered, or OnClick.  I tried to use an OnMouseUp event, and this does get fired at the right time, but seems to then disable the selection - so the event fires, but the listbox doesnt register a change in the status of the row being selected.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to do this, but it will require creating a class module with event handling to sub class your ListBoxes. A previous answer of mine dealt with a text box but you should be able to adapt the premise to your requirements for the ListBox. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509112/highlighting-textbox-content-upon-click/44510004#44510004

Comment: What event would I use in the class?

Comment: Sorry - my suggested solution is overkill and would be used for dynamic ListBoxes. Check here for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821968/get-values-from-a-listbox-on-a-sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed be using the ListBox_Change event to capture this. Upon any change you would need to enumerate through the items and see if they are selected to update any worksheet data

For example:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet: Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsTargetRange As Range: Set wsTargetRange = wsTarget.Range("A1:A100")

    Dim i As Long, RowIndex As Long

    RowIndex = 1
    wsTargetRange.ClearContents

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            wsTargetRange.Item(RowIndex) = ListBox1.List(i)
            RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to trigger the event.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    MsgBox "Something changed"
End Sub
```

Put this in the forms code.

Comment: This doesnt fire when a selection is made, I am using tick box mode for multi-select.  This only gets fired when I add items to it.

Comment: I dont want the Change event to fire apart from when a user makes a selection.  It is firing constantly, when the list is cleared, when its populated, when I change the selected state through code.  I only realy want it to be fired when a selection is made by a user.

Comment: You could disable the events with application.enableevents =False when the list is populating or clearing and application.enableevents=True when it has finished to solve that issue.  The last problem is are the Tick boxes necessary?

Comment: WIth Applcation.EnableEvents set to false, the change event still gets fired.  This doesnt surpress form level events

Comment: I am manually disabling the events using a variable, as recommended here:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm

Answer (score 0):

ctrlListBox.ListIndex

Os what you need.

[ctrlListBox.ListIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/listindex-property?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(fm20.chm2001430)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

It returns value of the last selected item. On change - it is the changed itemt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).