# Create images dynamically in vba and add click function to them

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to dynamically add images to a form in a grid like fashion. The images are from a folder for now then, I'm trying to add a click function to each dynamically created images on the form to execute something but I'm stuck on that part.   I am successful in importing the images to a form and showing it in a grid like fashion with the code below I came up with.

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Pic2_Click()
    'not working :(
    MsgBox "worked!!"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim img As Object
    Dim picSheet As Worksheet
     'Add Dynamic Image and assign it to object 'Img'

    Dim i, h, t As Integer
    ' Set picSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Themes")

    ' Dim pictureList As Object
    ' Dim pics As Shapes
    ' Dim pic As Shape
    ' Set pics = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Themes").Shapes
    Dim picPath As String
    t = 10
    h = 10
    
    picPath = Dir(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Pictures\*pic*") 'getting pictures from picpath folder image names are ranged from "pic1.jpg" to "pic12.jpg"
    Do While Not Blank(picPath) ' blank determines if a string is empty (boolean value)
     i = i + 1
     If i > 1 Then h = h + 90
        Set img = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.image.1", picPath, True)
            If i Mod 4 = 1 And i > 1 Then 'new row after first 4 images to create grid
                t = t + 100
                h = 10
            End If
        With img
            .Picture = LoadPicture(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Pictures\" & picPath)
            .PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeStretch
            .Left = h
            .Top = t
            .name = Split(picPath, ".")(0)
            Debug.Print "name is: " & .name
        End With
        picPath = Dir  
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You can look at using a control array: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah I tried that before, it didn't work for my case unfortunately.

Comment: Sure you only get mousedown/mouseup events but that might be enough to capture a "click"?

Comment: Here's the trick:  after you create the image, create a label exactly the same size and shape as the image tile and set the `BackStyle` property to `fmBackStyleTransparent` (make sure the `Caption` is empty). You now have a clickable image. The next thing you'll have to do is to capture the click event for that label-image. My suggestion is to create a custom class that creates both the image and the label. The `Label_Click` method in that class would have to dispatch the action you want it to take. The comment by @TimWilliams for the control array would be handy to manage the array.

Comment: You want an event handler array of command buttons which you can load pictures into, not a grid of images you are trying to get click events on. (you can do that but you would need to hook the window to get the cursor point then cross-reference with your existing control positions). An answer I gave a while ago highlights how to create an eventhandler array here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509112/highlighting-textbox-content-upon-click/44510004#44510004

Comment: I came up with an answer few weeks ago for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my entire solution and it worked for me. I changed a few things by using buttons instead that had the images embedded in them.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ColTB As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim picPath, path As String
    Dim i, h, t As Integer
    Dim button As Object
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    t = 10
    h = 10
    Set ColTB = New Collection
    
    picPath = Dir(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\Pictures\Themes\" & "*.jpg")
    Do While Not Blank(picPath)
    i = i + 1
    If i > 1 Then h = h + 120
    If i Mod 4 = 1 And i > 1 Then
        t = t + 100
        h = 10
    End If
    Set button = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", picPath, True)
    With button
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Left = h
        .Top = t
        .Picture = LoadPicture(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\Pictures\Themes\" & picPath)
        .Height = 72
        .Width = 100
    End With
    ColTB.Add EventObj(button)
    picPath = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

Function EventObj(obj As MSForms.CommandButton) As Class1
    Dim o As New Class1
    Set o.buttonClickEvent = obj
    Set EventObj = o
End Function
```

Class1  module

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents buttonClickEvent As MSForms.CommandButton


Private Sub buttonClickEvent_Click()
    Dim name, imgpath, sheetName As String
    Dim answer
    Dim ac As Worksheet
    Set ac = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    name = buttonClickEvent.name
    
    answer = MsgBox("You want to apply the " & Split(name, ".")(0) & " theme now?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Apply Theme")
    
    If answer = vbYes Then
        imgpath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\Pictures\Themes\" & name
        ac.SetBackgroundPicture Filename:=imgpath
    End If
    
End Sub
```