# Capturing double click event on Form Controls (Label control) in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I was hoping someone can help me with some VBA code related to Form Controls (Label). I'm converting one of our existing Excel based applications which is using many ActiveX controls to work on Mac thus I need to replace all the ActiveX components with Form Control ones, however it looks like the Form Control objects do not provide same event capturing as the ActiveX do (Mind you all the controls are located on the Sheets and not on UserForms). I need to be able capture double click event on the label which is very easy to do using ActiveX label but seems impossible using label under Form Controls. It looks like only even that any Form Control component supports is Click. Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: You are not mistaken https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Using-Visual-Basic-to-Customize-Outlook-Forms/control-events

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I thought this was the case but I'm still surprised that they only allow a click event to be captured where there are whole bunch of events for the same control using ActiveX. I wonder if I can mimic double click event by counting number of clicks that user does on that label.... I think that should work.

Comment: Yep that worked, just need to keep a count of the clicks, and if they do two clicks then execute required function.

Comment: Generally to handle events for these controls you would need to subclass the control then create an array of event handlers to capture the events you want. Something fairly similar is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44510004/3688861

Comment: Thanks, I think that would be the way to go for complex events, so that's good to know that its possible even though it adds more complexity into the whole code. To keep it simple within the function that is called by a click event I have added a counter along with a timer, if the user double clicks on the label then function which needs to be executed during double clicking will be executed, otherwise the click is ignored and counter is reset. Sorry I'm new here so not sure how to post my code so it comes out nicely formatted.

Comment: @Gatewave Since you have solved your own problem, you can submit an answer and accept it after few days. Don't worry about the formatting if you are not familiar with it, I'm sure someone will help you edit it.

Comment: Thanks, still trying to work out how this place works.